# How to move image with css/html

Tags: html, css

I am trying to move an image. I Want it to be alligned with the title "Experience". Here is my code

html code

```
<header>
    <h1>Experience</h1>
        <div class="logo">
            <img src="./img/exp.png">
        </div>
</header>
```

and the css code

```
.logo{
width: 100px;
    }

.logo img{
float: left;
margin-left: 0px 0px 0px 30px;
width: 150px;
height: 38px;
}
```

[image: layout]

Comment: Your `margin-left` property is invalid. `margin-left` takes one value, you may be looking for `margin`. Also how do you want it to be aligned. Next to the text?

Comment: Vertically with the text.

Comment: Well I assume you want it horizontally aligned to the left. In which case, remove the `float:left` and `margin` and use `position: absolute; left: 0px;` and set the header to `position: relative;` instead.

Comment: Stays in the same way. I want the image in that blue rectangle

Comment: It'll work. https://jsbin.com/nipitesama/edit?html,css,output

Comment: How aligned? Vertically or horizonatlly ?

Answer (score 2):

Just tweak the CSS a little:

```
.logo{
    width: 100px;
    display: inline-flex;
}

.logo img{
    margin: auto 5px;
    float: left;
    width: 150px;
    height: 38px;
}
```

Does this work?

This solution worked for me, but I have no idea for you as you didn't put your full code...

Answer (score 1):

Try adding float:left to .logo and setting display: inline-block on your h1, like so:

```
   *{
      margin: 0px;
      padding: 0px;
      font-family: Arial, Helvetica, Sans-serif;
      font-size: 34px
    }


    header{
        background-image: url(../img/bar.png);
        background-color: #00B9ED;
        height: 75px;
        border-bottom: 0px;
        padding-left: auto;
        padding-right: auto;
        width: 100%; 

    }   

    .logo{
        width: 100px;
        float: left;
        //display: inline-flex;
        }

    .logo img{
        margin: auto 5px;
        float: left;
        width: 150px;
        height: 38px;
    }
    h1 {
        display: inline-block;
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

How about making margin-left: 0%; and margin-right. Depends where you want to move it.
You used shorthand for margin-left. We use shorthand for margin only. You did margin-left: top right bottom left instead. I don't think the program reads that correctly.